# Math of Binomial distribution

Tags: probability

The manufacturer of a bag of sweets claims that there is $90$% chance that the bag contains some toffees. If $20$ bags are chosen what is the probability that all the bags contain toffees ?

It is binomial distribution

$$P(X)=\binom{20}{x}(.9)^x(1-.9)^{20-x}$$

But i am not understanding what is $X$ here ? number of bags ? or number of toffees ?

and what will be the math expression of all the bags contain toffees ?

Comment: The probability Bag $1$ contains some toffees is $0.9$, if the manufacturer is not lying. Same for Bag $2$, $3$, and so on. Ao (assuming independence) the probability they all do is $(0.9)^{20}$.

Comment: But your formula is correct, where x is the number of bags that should contain at least one toffee. And it reduces to the answer in the previous comment when x=20.